# using for loop (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a list:

```
List<FaAccount> accounts = someMethod();
```

this list contains `accountid`, `currency`, `balance`. Now I want to aggregate balance by currency (sum of balance for each currency). I've created new class with `currency` and `balance` variables. This, only copies info from `FaAccount` into `FaAccountBalance`

```
List<FaAccountBalance> aggr = new ArrayList<>();
for(FaAccount account : accounts){
            FaAccountBalance ag = new FaAccountBalance();
            ag.setCurrency(account.getCurrency());
            ag.setBalance(account.getBalance());
            aggr.add(ag);
}
```

How can I put there (into aggr `List`) one more `for` loop or some other technique, so that to represent sum of balance for each currency?

Comment: Where do you want to put the loop exactly and what do you want to sum up ? I dont get your question...

Comment: @Kami, I want to sum up balance, grouped by currency. For instance, in accounts there may be ['USD', 500], ['USD',200]. In aggr, I want ['USD',700]. The question is where and how I can use for loop for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a different for loop, you can do it in the same for loop using a `HashMap`

```
List<FaAccountBalance> aggr = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(FaAccount account : accounts){
        String currency = account.getCurrency();
        int balance =account.getBalance();
        FaAccountBalance ag = new FaAccountBalance();
        ag.setCurrency(currency);
        ag.setBalance(balance);
        aggr.add(ag);        
        map.put(currency,map.getOrDefault(currency,0) + balance);
}
```

After this for loop, you will have aggregated balance for each currency, just print it like:

```
for(String currency: map.keySet()){
    System.out.println(currency + " : " + map.get(currency));
}
```

**UPDATE** If you want a `BigDecimal`, you can't just add it with `+`. You have to use `add`

```
map.put(currency,map.getOrDefault(currency, BigDecimal.ZERO).add(new BigDecimal(balance)));
```

If you want to Store it in List, instead of printing the hashmap contents, add them to the list.

```
List< FaAcountBalance> result  = new LinkedList<>();
for(String currency: map.keySet()){
    result.add(new FaAcountBalance(currency,map.get(currency)));
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks. what about map.put(currency,map.getOrDefault(currency,BigDecimal.ZERO) + balance); what is wrong? i've changed HashMap to BigDecimal, and is it going to return me desired list ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, it just depends on what type you want to use for aggregated `balance`.

Comment: as BigDecimal, it says getOrDefault(Object,BigDecimal) in Map cannot be applied to BifDecimal

Comment: @Sher oh you are talking about the syntax error, I updated my answer. You can't use `+` directly.

Comment: Almost done. One last question, how to put what is in Map into List?

Comment: what do you want to put in List? only `keys` in Map or only `values` or both?

Comment: List<FaAcountBalance>

Comment: Because it should return list, so that I can use it in JavaFX TableView

Comment: @Sher updated the solution, Just create a new list from Hashmap while iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

First, your design is not ideal, you have some redundancy. Indeed, you are explicitly **copying** information, this suggests it is not clear for you who should own this data. I would suggest this better approach :

```
public class FaAccount {
    private final FaAccountBalance balance;
    private final int accountId;
}

public class FaAccountBalance {
    private float amount;
    private Currency currency;
}
```

The aggregation is then pretty easy :

```
Map<Currency, Double> aggregation = new HashMap<>();
for (FaAccount account : accounts) {
   FaAccountBalance balance = account.getBalance();
   aggregation.put(balance.getCurrency(), aggregation.getOrDefault(0) + balance.getAmount());
}
```

Finally,

```
List<FaAccountBalance> aggregatedBalances = 
    aggregation.entrySet()
               .map(entry -> new FaAccountBalance(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: and how to put it into List?

Comment: To put what into which list

Comment: Why I can't put BigDecimal.ZERO into getOrDefaultBalance? I've changed Double to BigDecimal

Comment: You don't give enough details for me to answer. Did you update it everywhere you need ? Do you have an compile error message ?

Comment: No, just syntax error, because Balance is not Integer, it is BigDecimal

Comment: karthik gave you the answer : you cannot sum `BigDecimal`s with `+`. I would add that your question was not complete enough for us to give a complete answer. Think about it next time, you could have included a small snippet of each of your classes to show us the data types

Answer (score 1):

An other option would consist of using `Collectors.groupingBy` then simply map each `Map.Entry` into a `FaAccountBalance` and collect them as list :

```
final List<FaAccountBalance> accountBalances = 
    accounts
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FaAccount::getCurrency, Collectors.summingInt(FaAccount::getBalance)))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> {
            final FaAccountBalance f = new FaAccountBalance();
            f.setCurrency(entry.getKey());
            f.setBalance(entry.getValue());
            return f;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Java 8 streams are so unreadable and uneasy to use... One reason is Java compiler's terrible inference type, and the other reason is that the API is just not easily discoverable. I did not know about `summingInt`, which makes your answer helpful. However, I now consider Java streams as a pain unless you just want to perform simple operations. Scala has a much better API.

Comment: @Dici Seems like we have divergent opinions here, I've always found the stream API very intuitive and don't find it hard to read at all. In fact, also doing scala, I find the Java API more readable. However, I must say that I find the Scala one more complete.

Comment: One thing I don't like is the `collect` approach. It leads you to have deeply nested expressions if you want to do complex stuff with multiple `collectingAndThen`. I prefer `list.groupBy(...).mapValues(...)` over `list.collect(groupingBy(...), summingInt(...))`.  Also, `stream()` clutters the code, and it's even worse for a `Map` on which you must first call either `entrySet, values, keySet`. You have 3 lines of these in your code, which add nothing to the logic. I'm not criticizing your answer, which is ok, but the Java API.